# Better way to deal with date in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, date

I have a form where the user has to input one begin date and one end date. After that, I have to compute the result of this date to have a status on the UI:

- if dates are in the past, status is "DONE"
- if dates are in the future, status is "TO BE DONE"
- if today is bewteen the two dates, status is "IN PROGRESS"

How can I compute that easely? I have date in the form with that format: 04/21/2015.

Do you recommand me to compare date by changing format (04/21/2015 => 20150421) and compare? Or use Date of JS? or anything else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I can do both

Comment: try the thing called - moment.js

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh overkill - plus it doesn't have comparisons unless you include moment-range. I would just be comparing Unix timestamps

Comment: @Sarvesh I don't need moment.js but thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get two date objects like this:

```
// parse a date in mm/dd/yyyy format
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.split('/');
  // new Date(year, month [, day [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[0]-1, parts[1]); // Note: months are 0-based
}
```

Then compare using usual operators `< > ==`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a date object for the input date and another date object for the current date and then, simply compare them.

Check the [dateObject](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) in order to provide the correct date string format:

```
var inpDate = $('input').val();
var d = new Date(inpDate);
var today = new Date();

if (inpDate > today) {
   return "TO BE DONE";
} else ....
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried http://momentjs.com/ . Real easy to use, conversion and formatting could save you time adding further JavaScript code however it is offset by adding the library.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getStatusByDate(startDate, endDate) {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    var startTime = new Date(startDate).getTime();
    var endTime = new Date(endDate).getTime();
    console.log(startTime, endTime);
    if (startTime < endTime && endTime < currentTime) {
        return ('DONE');
    } else if (startTime < endTime && endTime > currentTime && startTime < currentTime) {
        return ('IN PROGRESS');
    } else if (startTime < endTime && startTime > currentTime) {
        return ('TO BE DONE');
    } else {
        return ('INVALID INPUT');
    }
}
```